# How can we prove it? ${a}{b}≤\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$

Tags: inequality, young-inequality

$(i)$ $a>0,b>0,p>0,q>0$

$(ii)$ $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

> How can we prove it?

${a}{b}≤\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$